# Does QFT renormalization preserve Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, renormalization

In the Wilsonian picture, a renormalized theory is about change of scale. As we change scale for a quantum field theory, does the Hilbert space of a theory remain unchanged?

Comment: It changes. In the UV you have all sort of fields hanging around, and their associated states lie in the Hilbert space of the theory. Flowing to the IR the fat ones are left out so only the light fields are there, hence only the light states are in the Hilbert space

Comment: But when you renormalize a theory one is not necessarily speaking about an effective field theory, namely all fields and d.o.f's should still be there, how is this explained?

Comment: Extreme example: take a theory with a mass gap and renormalise all the way to the deep IR. The resulting theory is empty.

Comment: @st.vit I'm not sure that counts as an explanation. The UV fields are still there no matter how far into the IR you go, unless you go all the way to infinity, which is only an idealisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can think of a quantum field theory as an association between observables and regions of spacetime: for each spacetime region $\cal{O}$, we have a collection $\cal{A}(\cal{O})$ of observables. Together with a representation of all of these observables as operators on a single Hilbert space, this is the only data that needs to be specified. (The data must satisfy some conditions, but there is no additional *data*.)

Conceptually, in the Wilson picture, renormalization amounts to a simple two-step process:

- Step 1: For some $\lambda>0$, replace each $\cal{A}(\cal{O})$ with $\cal{A}(\lambda\cal{O})$, where $\lambda\cal{O}$ is the image of $\cal{O}$ under a scale transformation of spacetime.
- Step 2: Re-scale the *units* so that $\lambda\cal{O}$ has the same size in the new units that $\cal{O}$ had in the original units.

Does this change the Hilbert space? For a typical quantum field theory in continuous spacetime, the original Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional (think about the effect of continuous translations), and so is the new one. Up to isomorphism, there is only one separable infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space, so the Hilbert space must remain the same (for finite values of $\lambda$, at least).

There are two possible loopholes:

- In the case of a lattice QFT, the Hilbert space may be finite-dimensional. Then the preceding argument fails.
- This one is a semantic loophole. In the quantum (field) theory literature, the expression "Hilbert space" sometimes implicitly refers to the net of observables as well as to the Hilbert space. For example, some authors may refer to the Hilbert space of square-integrable functions of a single real variable and the Hilbert space of square-integrable functions of two real variables as two different Hilbert spaces, when in fact they are the *same* Hilbert space in two different representations, each tailored to a different net of observables. The *observables* — at least their association to regions of spacetime — certainly *do* change under renormalization in the Wilson picture, and I suppose some authors might describe this as a change of the Hilbert space.